# How to workaround variables in variables?

Tags: python

I need to be able to define to variables, but with each variable having the other in it's definition.

I'm in a python class as a complete beginner, and having almost finished a homework assignment, I have realized that my code is not working because of a core element of implementation about python.
You can't call two variables inside of each other.
This is necessary because I am writing a text based adventure game, and so, for multiple core components of the program, I have referenced other variables inside of variables for things like being able to go back to the same room and referencing a scene in an item so I can use it in a function. I can't post the direct code because it's a homework assignment and the teacher will search online for copies of the code, but I have written some general code:

```
class obj():
   def __init__(self,name)
      self.name=name
dave=obj(maurice)
maurice=obj(dave)
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Initially do `dave=obj(None)`, followed by `maurice=obj(dave)`, and then lastly `dave.name=maurice)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have circular references in Python code. The interpreter executes instructions one at a time, so state has to be updated in a specific order and Python will not make this decision for you. With that set aside, there is no problem in having one object "obtaining" a reference before the related object does, as your game should not be  playable between updates.

Your typical game loop looks like this:

```
stop_processing_player_input()
update_state()
resume_processing_player_input()
```

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.friends = {}
        self.name = name

    def become_friends(self, friend):
        self.friends.add(friend)
        friend.add(self)

resume_processing_input()
# player does things, dave and maurice
# are born and instantly become friends

stop_processing_player_input()

# begin state update
dave = Person(name='Dave')
maurice = Person(name='Maurice')

dave.become_friends(maurice)
# dave.friends.add(maurice)
# maurice.friends.add(dave)
# end state update

resume_processing_player_input()
```